# Get all children that have same parent with one of the child's values

Tags: soql

How can I get all children of the parent based off of one of the child's values?

```
SELECT Feature__c, FeatureTwo__c
FROM Child__c
WHERE Parent__c
IN (SELECT Parent__c.Id
    FROM Child__c
    WHERE FeatureTwo__c = 'abc')
```

This gives me an error that says:
**The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type**

Is there a way to do this in one query instead of two separate queries?

Comment: This data model strikes me as odd. The way your query is written appears to be attempting to get all of the children of any parent that has any child whose `FeatureTwo__c` field is `'abc'`. Is that really what you want? What's the relationship between the feature fields and the parent object?

Comment: @DavidReed yes that is correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do this with a single query.

The query that you have right now is an example of a *semijoin*, but what you need is a *parent-child subquery*.

In a nutshell, query from the parent object, and include a subquery in the `SELECT` clause. You can use filters inside of that subquery to achieve what you're looking to do

```
[
SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT Id FROM Children__r WHERE Field__c = 'value') 
FROM Parent
WHERE ParentField__c IN :parentValuesToQuery
]
```

One thing to keep in mind is that in your subquery, you need to use the *child relationship name* specified in the master-detail or lookup field on the child object.

The child relationship name usually follows the pattern:

- Plural of object name
- with "__r" appended to the end (if it's a custom field that defines your relationship

e.g. `Opportunities` if you want to query the Opportunities related to a given Account, `Circuits__r` if you have a `Circuit` custom object.

There are some exceptions like `ChildAccounts` when you want to query the "child" accounts related to another Account via the `ParentId` field.

Also good to keep in mind is how to access subquery results.

A subquery will end up as a List of the relevant SObject type, embedded in the results list of the outermost query. You access and manipulate this list just like you would any other.

For my example:

```
List<Parent> parentResults = <query goes here>;
for(Parent p :parentResults){
    List<Child> children = p.Children__r;

    // Now, children contains all of the child records related to the current parent
    // 'p'
}
```

The [using relationship queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using) documentation page goes into a little more detail.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you clarify. Do you mean: `SELECT Id, 
    (SELECT Id FROM Children__r WHERE Field__c = 'value') 
FROM Parent
WHERE ParentField__c IN (SELECT Id FROM Children__r WHERE Field__c = 'value') ` I get a Bind variables only allowed in Apex code from your first example.

Comment: @user60749 No, that's not really what I meant, and yes, my example would only work in Apex (not, say, through the query tab of the developer console). The takeaway here is: 1) Use a parent-child subquery and 2) Find some way to limit the number of parent object records that you're querying. I don't think a semi-join is appropriate in your particular situation.